# ActionView::MissingTemplate with Dropzonejs

Tags: ruby-on-rails, paperclip, dropzone.js

I am facing this error, when I upload the image in the dropzone ( it's like the previewer in the form) and I don't see what's happening.
I have all the views thought...

```
ActionView::MissingTemplate (Missing template finished_guitars/show, application/show with {:locale=>[:en], :formats=>[:json], :variants=>[], :handlers=>[:raw, :erb, :html, :builder, :ruby, :jbuilder]}. Searched in:
  * "/Users/Billy/code/guitar_app/app/views"
):
```

I have two models:

**finished_guitar** that has a relation with **attachment**,
 I am using **paperclip** to upload images in **attachment**

I believe that my models are ok:

**attachment.rb**

```
class Attachment < ApplicationRecord
    belongs_to :finished_guitar
    has_attached_file :image, styles: { medium: "300x300>", thumb: "120x120>" }, default_url: "/images/:style/missing.png"
    validates_attachment_content_type :image, :content_type => ["imagse/jpg", "images/jpeg", "images/png"]
end
```

**finished_guitar.rb**

```
class FinishedGuitar < ApplicationRecord
    accepts_nested_attributes_for :attachments, allow_destroy: true
    has_many :attachments
end
```

I must be wrong somewhere in the controllers:

**attachments_controller.rb**

```
class AttachmentsController < ApplicationController

  def create
    @attachment = Attachment.new(attachment_params)
    respond_to do |format|
      if @attachment.save
        format.html { redirect_to @finished_guitar, notice: 'Attachment was successfully created.' }
        format.json { render :show, status: :created, location: @attachment }
      else
        format.html { render :new }
        format.json { render json: @attachment.errors, status: :unprocessable_entity }
      end
    end
  end

  private
    def attachment_params
      params.require(:attachment).permit(:id, :finished_guitar_id, :image)
    end
end
```

**finished_guitars_controller.rb**

```
class FinishedGuitarsController < ApplicationController

    def index
        @finished_guitars = FinishedGuitar.all
    end

    def show
        @finished_guitar = FinishedGuitar.find(params[:id])
        @attachments = @finished_guitar.attachments.all
    end

    def new
        @finished_guitar = FinishedGuitar.new
        @attachments = @finished_guitar.attachments.build
    end


    def create  
        @finished_guitar = FinishedGuitar.new(finished_guitar_params)
    respond_to do |format|
      if @finished_guitar.save
        unless params[:attachments].nil?
            params[:attachments]['image'].each do |a|
                @finished_guitar = @finished_guitar.attachments.create!(:image => a)
            end
        end
        format.html { redirect_to @finished_guitar, notice: 'Guitartest was successfully created.' }
        format.json { render :show, status: :created, location: @finished_guitar }
      else
        format.html { render :new }
        format.json { render json: @finished_guitar.errors, status: :unprocessable_entity }
      end
    end
    end

    def destroy
        @finished_guitar = FinishedGuitar.find(params[:id])
        @finished_guitar.destroy
    end


    private
        def finished_guitar_params
            params.require(:finished_guitar).permit(:title, :description, attachments_attributes: [:finished_guitar_id, :id, :image])
        end
end
```

### Edit:

**app/views/finished_guitars/_form.html.erb**

```
<div class="content">
    <%= simple_form_for @finished_guitar, html: {multipart: true, id: "my-dropzone", class: "dropzone"} do |f| %>
        <%= f.input :title %>
        <%= f.input :description %>

        <div class="dz-message needsclick">
            <h3>Drop file here</h3> or
            <strong>click</strong> to upload
        </div>
        <div class="fallback">

            <%= simple_fields_for :attachments do |ff| %>
                <%= ff.input_field :image %>
            <% end %>
        </div>
            <%= f.button :submit, class: "btn btn-primary" %>
    <% end %>

</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

That error is telling you a view is missing. Specifically a file called `show.html.erb` in your `views/finished_guitars` folder.  Do you have a file called `show.html.erb` in your `views/finished_guitars/` folder?

If you look at the error you can see what I mean `ActionView::MissingTemplate (Missing template finished_guitars/show` . It is an `ActionView` error and the error exactly is `MissingTemplate` which means a view file is missing, then it tells you which one `finished_guitars/show`

I also just want to make sure, is there a typo in the folder's name? `app/views/finished_guitasr/_form.html.erb` where it says `.../finished_guitasr/...`. Or did you jsut write it like that in the question?

Comment: it's a typo in the question sorry, I will update.
I have created all the views, so none is missing.
This error message appear in my rails s console when I upload the images. I still can post my `finished_guitar` even if attachments are not uploading, and the `show.html.erb` display the title and the description but not the images.